# So if my tv does not work well and the hdmi is still plugged in and I unplug the cord for the tv out of the wall frequently will it damage my xbox?

Tags: xbox-one

So this is what happened my tv does not turn on very well but it will still turn on but if I keep on unplugging the cord connected to the wall since the hdmi is still plugged in will it damage my Xbox if I do this frequently and if it does how badly?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe it would?

Comment: You'll probably upgrade to next Xbox version long before either console or hdmi cable has any issues. That said, you could always get a power strip with on/off button if you don't want to keep unplugging the power cord.

Answer (score 0):

No.

If anything, your HDMI cable will be damaged long before your console.

Comment: Just to add to this, plunging and unplugging any sort of connector causes friction that leads to wear and tear. It's not going to hurt the console (Xbox, Playstation, Wii/Swtich) whenever the display is disconnected, but doing it repeatedly will cause the port to eventually loosen. This may take years, but it's still avoidable wear and tear when possible.